# How to set precision of results returned by Google Maps v3 API directionsService?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The google maps v3 directionsService returns lat/long points that are sometimes longer than I want. Here is a call I might make:

```
var request = {
    origin: start_position, 
    destination: end_position,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        // do something with response, e.g. set the overview_path to a polyline;
    }
});
```

The resulting response might return the following values for a point:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.Xa = 35.077000000000005    
response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.Ya = -85.08854000000001
```

I really want to lessen the precision. For example I would prefer values to a precision of five decimal places like this:

```
Xa = 35.07700    
Ya = -85.08854
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? I have looked through the documentation and I don't see any mention of a way to set this.

Thanks for any insight or help you might offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't use .Xa and .Ya because those are minified names that can change with the next release of the API. Instead you should use the documented methods lat() and lng(). so:

```
response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat()= 35.077000000000005    
response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng() = -85.08854000000001
```

and if you want to round the decimals then you'd use the standard javascript method .toFixed(), that is:

```
var lat = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lat().toFixed(5);// 35.07700    
var lon = response.routes[0].legs[0].start_location.lng().toFixed(5);// -85.08854
```

Comment: Good point on using .lat() and .lng() I am aware I can set each individual lat/long using javascript, however this would get very expensive very quickly for long lines. I am looking for a setting that will allow me to set this as an option when I make the call.

Comment: You cannot configure the precision that someone else's server, (Google's), responds with. You can only manipulate the data after you received it.

Comment: Obviously I can't *configure* their server. However, if there was a parameter that could be passed as an option I could request it to be returned at a certain precision. It is no different than requesting that the results are returned using **travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING** vs. **google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING**

Comment: Well, you can't because there is no such option, and in any case it is so trivial that I can't imagine Google may ever implement it.

Comment: Well hopefully one day they will. It doesn't make much sense to return results in decimal lat/long form that are equivalent in precision to, literally, partial angstroms. Thanks for trying to help though. I see you have a lot of experience in using the google maps API and I appreciate you trying to help. I am sure I will have more questions soon :)

Comment: If you think you'll have more questions, remember that up-voters get priority. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript uses double precision floating point numbers](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference) to represent data.  If you are saving that data as a string, it might make sense to output it using .toFixed(); but that would be your code, not Google's.