# Setting Accuracy of Google Geocoder Results

Tags: google-maps, google-api, geocoding

I get latitude and longitude values as geocoder results by using codes I got from http://www.phpmoot.com/php-get-latitudelongitude-from-an-address-with-google-map/. What I want is setting the results to have just two digits behind the ".". For example 137.3463566 to be 137.34. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You want *less* accuracy? Is there a reason you can't just round it yourself?

Comment: @DanielPryden has your answer, I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208840/how-to-set-precision-of-results-returned-by-google-maps-v3-api-directionsservice/12208981#12208981). You cannot control what Google sends you, but you can discard what you don't need.

you can use toFixed(), as in

```
var lat = map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(2); // keep only 2 decimals
var lon = map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(2); // keep only 2 decimals
```

and if you want to round it on the PHP side:

```
$lat = round($output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,2);
$long = round($output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng,2);
```